# How to pass a global variable to the HTTP body (form-data)?

Tags: katalon-studio

I am currently using Katalon Studio (V 6.1.4) to test webservices and i am just starting with katalon.
My question is how can i pass a global variable to the HTTP body?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is a detailed tutorial about this topic: https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/parameterize-a-web-service-object.html#query-parameters

You need to use code like this:

```
findTestObject('myTestObject', [('yourParam') : GlobalVariables.yourGlobalVar]))
```